# Can someone please tell me what += does in java for example i += 2;

Tags: java

Can someone please tell me what += means in java, for example i +=2;
Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Have you even searched anything on that?

Comment: the level of quality of the questions decreasing :(

Comment: Might want to try making the title match the question.

Comment: @ivanovic.. Still we got 3 answers already. ;)

Comment: Someone should probably detail the multi-threading implications of +=.

Comment: @ChrisGerken did you mean `quality -= 1`?

Comment: @pamphlet: What are those implications? Haven't heard about it.

Comment: @Nambari My comment was tongue-in-cheek, but merely that the read and assignment aren't atomic. So for example, if i starts at 0, two threads performing i += 2 won't necessarily result in the value being 4.

Answer (score 1):

It adds `2` to the value of `i`. It is a shorthand for

```
i = i + 2
```

Answer (score 0):

`Val1 += Val2` means add `Val2` to `Val1` and assign the result to `Val1`.

It's a very common need, that's why it's built in to most languages.